# json-simple.jar is missing from spring boot war

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-3, war, maven-war-plugin

The `json-simple` jar is missing in packaged WAR because it is marked as `optional` in `spring-boot-starter-parent`, BUT I do include a dependency `gelfj` that declares `json-simple` as dependency..... example below (used with Maven **3.3.3**):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.giveandtake</groupId>
  <artifactId>main</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

  <name>main</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graylog2</groupId>
            <artifactId>gelfj</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

[1] when packaging war with maven 3.0.4 i get the json-simple inside war (without asking for the jar explicitly).

[2] when packaging with maven 3.3.x war i dont have this jar in my war(unless i explicitly ask for it) file.

which leaves me with these questions:

**Question 1**: if i have ProjectX-->(Inherit)Spring-boot-Parent and also declare a dependency Y that has dependency for json-simple, shouldnt the dependency for simple-json be transitive into war and recognize that as not optional anymore?

**Question 2**: why is the different results with different maven versions [maven bug? , searched for release notes but didnt find anything matching]

Comment: The details of this issue in Spring Boot: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38555184/466738 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6450. Will be fixed in Spring Boot 1.3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if i have ProjectX-->(Inherit)Spring-boot-Parent and also declare a dependency Y that has dependency for json-simple, shouldnt the dependency for simple-json be transitive into war and recognize that as not optional anymore?

The `spring-boot-starter-parent` pom declares the `json-simple` dependency as `optional` in its `dependencyManagement` section (and not in its `dependencies` section):

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
         </dependency>
         ...
```

`dependencyManagement` has a strong governance over declared dependencies and transitive dependencies, making in this case `json-simple` as `optional` for any transitive dependency (re-defining its mediation hence) of your declared dependencies, that's why it would not be added to the packaged `war` (even if the `gelfj` dependency has it as transitive dependency).

From [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> A second, and very important use of the dependency management section is to control the versions of artifacts used in transitive dependencies
>   [...]  dependency management takes precedence over dependency mediation for transitive dependencies.

---

> why is the different results with different maven versions [maven bug? , searched for release notes but didnt find anything matching]

Maven 3.0.4 is has a [default binding](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-core/default-bindings.html) to Maven War Plugin version **2.1.1**, while Maven 3.3.3 has a [default binding](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html) to Maven War Plugin version **2.2**, that's the main difference concerning the two Maven versions and the War plugin.

However, the `spring-boot-starter-parent` pom declares the WAR plugin as version **2.5** in its `pluginManagement`, hence impacting the version you will finally use as part of your build and removing the difference above between the two maven versions.

So this was a Maven Core bug rather than a WAR Plugin bug and [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5145) looks pretty much the fix (in the Maven version **3.1.0**).

Upon my tests, I was able to reproduce the following scenarios:

- Maven **3.0.4**, no `gelfj` dependency declared, hence `json-simple` inherited as optional, WAR plugin did not package it: CORRECT BEHAVIOR
- Maven **3.3.3**, no `gelfj` dependency declared, again `json-simple` as optional, not packaged: CORRECT BEHAVIOR
- Maven **3.0.4**, `gelfj` dependency declared, `json-simple` should still be as optional, WAR Plugin did package it: **INCORRECT BEHAVIOR**
- Maven **3.3.3**, `gelfj` dependency declared, again `json-simple` still optional, WAR Plugin did not package it: CORRECT BEHAVIOR

I would hence suggest to rather upgrade your maven version (recommended, avoid **3.0.4**) or explicitly declared the dependency as not optional (by declaring it as your dependency, for instance, or as not optional in your `dependencyManagement` section).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dependency management entry for json-simple with optional=true
in your parents, this might lead to the described situation.
Have a look at the effective pom in eclipse or with `mvn help effective-pom`
than search for any occurence of json-simple it might help.

For the version differences : You might use effective-pom for this, also