# json-simple marked as optional under spring-boot-dependencies - intentional?

Tags: spring-boot

Under all spring-boot-dependencies versions

json-simple is the only one with optional set to true.  is it intentional?

upcoming maven 3.4 honors this setting and will break some existing builds

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>${simple-json.version}</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Detail discussion is at http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Re-Preleminary-Maven-3-4-0-SNAPSHOT-Testing-Take-3-td5876004.html

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be marked as optional in `spring-boot-dependencies`. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6450) so that we can fix the bom. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.